# Quick way to check if an integer is 2^n times another integer

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation

Given two strictly positive integers *x* and *y* expressed in base 2, is there a quick way to check if *x = 2^n y* where *n* is an integer? (That's the same as checking if *x* is a shifted version of *y*, but I'm not sure this is actually easier.)

One solution is to check that *x % y = 0* and that *x / y* is a power of two (which can be done very efficiently [1]) but this requires a modulo and a division, two expensive operations, even on modern architectures.

[1] *x* is a power of two if and only if *(x & (x - 1)) = 0*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modulo and division might be merged into the same operation, but it would still be slow.

An other approach is, as you mention, trying some `n`'s. Which `n`'s? You can do a binary search. This is, of course, also slow. Whether it's faster or slower than the first approach, well, who knows. Depends on how fast division is for one, which is not the same on every processor.

If you have a `numberOfTrailingZeros` primitive (aka `tzcnt` or almost-equivalently `ffs` or `_BitscanForward`), you can normalize `x` and `y` like this:

```
int nx = x >> tzcnt(x);
int ny = y >> tzcnt(y);
```

Then if `nx == ny`, `x` is a power-of-two multiple of `y`, but it might be a negative power of two, so you also have to check that `tzcnt(x) >= tzcnt(y)`.

edit: I suppose checking whether `x >= y` is enough to catch that case.

Comment: Your normalization idea is interesting! I'm on x64, and yes I do have access to `_BitscanForward`.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune ok, `bsf` is different from `tzcnt` for an argument of 0, which doesn't matter in this case because zero shifted by any amount is still zero

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to complain about the inordinate effort of division and modulus operations, then just repeatedly shift and compare the bit patterns.  That's easiest.  However, assuming 64-bit integers, and assuming uniform distribution (which is probably invalid), it would take an average of 32 shift and compare iterations to perform this test.  Whether shifting and comparing 32 times is faster than one integer division and a couple of subtractions and ANDs is doubtful.  Check the processor handbook if you're uncertain.